# Método Java que retorna diferença em horas

Tags: java

Porque o método abaixo está retornando -1? Ele deve retornar a diferença em horas entre duas datas.

```
public int diferencaHoras(String h1, String h2) throws ParseException{

     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

     Date d1 = df.parse (h1);
     Date d2 = df.parse (h2);

    long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
    int diffHours = (int) (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24);

    return diffHours;
}
```

Se eu chamar o método com os parâmetros:

```
diferencaHoras("02/01/2018 23:00", "03/01/2018 12:00");
```

retorna -1

Comment: Você pode transformar as datas em timeInMillis subtrair a maior pela menor e depois converter em horas, forma mais simples. =D

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica Guilherme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque a linha:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
```

por

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

De acordo com os parâmetros da chamada

> diferencaHoras("02/01/2018 23:00", "03/01/2018 12:00");

o resultado será -13, já que a data de valor maior está após o operador.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rafael! Era isso mesmo. Valeu!

Answer (score 4):

O erro em seu código está no `pattern` da data. No *Java*, `hh:mm` significa: "Horas de 1 à 12 : minutos de 0 à 59".

Como não tem o `PM/AM` para diferenciar manhã e tarde, o *Java* fica "confuso" e ao interpretar `12:45`, ele acha que é `00:45`

Seu código está convertendo **03/01/2018 12:00** para **03/01/2018 00:00**

Dessa forma teremos **03/01/2018 23:00** - **03/01/2018 00:00** = -1 hora. Por isso seu retornado está retornando **-1**.

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/GosexI

Comment: Muito obrigado Valdeir! Eu desconfiava disso, mas não estava entendo como ele estava interpretando essa diferença de 12/24hs.

Answer (score 2):

O Java 8 adicionou novas classes para o tratamento de questões como diferença entre datas e duração de eventos na especificação JSR-310. Segue abaixo um exemplo da classe **Duration**, da especificação:

```
import java.time.Duration;

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime dt1= LocalDateTime.parse("01-01-2018 10:30:00", f);
LocalDateTime dt2= LocalDateTime.parse("08-01-2018 16:00:00", f);

long diferencaMili = Duration.between(dt1, dt2).toMillis();
long diferencaSeg = Duration.between(dt1, dt2).getSeconds();
long diferencaMin = Duration.between(dt1, dt2).toMinutes();
```

Caso você não esteja usando Java 8, existe um [backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) para Java 6, 7 e Android.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!!